# Build a NuGet package from project but without any references

Tags: nuget, t4, nuget-package

I have created a T4 template that I want to reuse in several projects using NuGet. This template is based on a custom class so I need to distribute a DLL with the template. The DLL is used by the template during generation, but is not used by the project itself so I do NOT want it added to the target project as a reference.

My .nuspec file includes my DLL and places it in the root of the package which will prevent it from creating a reference and everything works fine if I build my package by hand. Unfortunately, I want to use the "nuget pack" command to automatically pick up the version number.  When I run this command and reference the project file, it includes my DLL twice, once in the root (as I specified in my nuspec file) and an additional time in the lib folder (along with everything in the bin folder).

How can I automatically build my NuGet package without including any references. It seems there are several solutions, but I can't figure any of them out:

1. Let nuget include my DLL in the lib folder, but prevent it from creating the reference. I know I can use the `<references>` section to reference some DLLs and not others, but in this case I don't want it to reference any. If I leave the `<references>` section blank it is either ignored or I get an error depending on what level I leave blank.
2. Prevent nuget from including any DLLs automatically and *only* include the files in the `<files>` section of the nuspec file. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to build the package from the project file without it including my DLL automatically.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If you right-click the DLL, you'll probably see that its "build action" is set to "content". Try setting it to "none".